# How to generate a video using cv2 python

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, opencv, python

I have a project to do. I have scraped some data from some website. I have to create a video using data scraped and one screenshot. One background image is also included. 
an example is shown below. 
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUnRm.png)

Picture of Leonel Messi or any player and the background image ofc will remain there, only stats will change as there are many. 
Can somebody give me some piece of code or guide me how can I create such video?

Comment: Just use `ffmpeg`

Comment: How to use it, can you give me some example?

Comment: is ffmpeg a python module?